# Wrong orientation of a diode destroy a circuit (Schematic included)

Tags: diodes, pwm, electromagnet

[image: power]

I get 24V from the barrel jack.

[image: magnet]

The electromagnet is controlled  using PWM.

Here, I made a mistake and the diode direction is reversed. (The diode is placed to protect from back EMF.)

When I plugged in the power it maded a sound and the power adapter shut off automatically.

After this, I removed the electromagnet and plugged the power in again, but now the adapter always shuts off after some milliseconds.

[image: led]

Before I tried the electromagnet, the power adapter worked well and thed LED turns on. After I connected the electromagnet with the wrong diode direction, it stopped working.

I know I made a mistake with the diode, but I am not sure if this can destroy the circuit. If so, how? If I simply fix the diode position, this will be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have destroyed the MOSFET (possibly physically popped) and perhaps the diode as well. If there is 24V there, then the power supply is okay. Putting the diode in reverse means that the current through both the MOSFET and the diode would be very (destructively) high (limited only by the part characteristics and the power supply capacity).

Suggest replacing both the diode and MOSFET if you can't test the former (multimeter diode mode, for example). If you've caused the diode to go short then then replacement MOSFET will be toast as well as soon as it is turned on.